# Save the output of a command to a variable

Tags: text-processing, command-line

The command `mid3v2 -l someFile.mp3`
gives the following output for a file with name `someFile.mp3` in mp3-format:

```
IDv2 tag info for someFile.mp3
APIC=cover front,  (image/jpg, 52016 bytes)
TALB=someAlbumName
TCON=amusicGenre
TDRC=2000
TIT2=songname
TPE1=singer
TPE2=singer
TRCK=1
```

I would like to store the value of TPE1 to a variable `t` for further processing. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to answer this question.
The first step is to understand that the output of a command could be received  by other commands via a pipe, or, could be captured in a variable:

```
cmd | next command ... etc
var=$(cmd)
```

The process to select a line and further select what is after the sign `=` is called "text processing" and the shell is not well suited to do it.

A common way to do it may be sed:

```
 $ mid3v2 -l someFile.mp3 | sed -En 's/^TPE1=(.*)$/\1/p'
 Singer
```

And capture the result to a variable:

```
$ t=$(mid3v2 -l someFile.mp3 | sed -En 's/^TPE1=(.*)$/\1/p')
$ echo "$t"
Singer
```

There is no simple equivalent inside a simple shell. On higher shells (ksh,bash,zsh) it is possible to use regex. Which shell do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Given your shell provides "process substitution", you might try "sourcing" the result:

```
. <(mid3v2 -l someFile.mp3 | grep -o "[^ ]*=[^ ]*")
t=$TPE1
```

Comment: This seem rather unsafe though.